# Freezing some layers in Keras has slower training time

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I have two identically structured keras models. One is a standard DNN and one is the same archetecture with some layers set to `trainable=False`. They both are able to get comparable accurate results.\

I assumed the network with frozen weights would be faster to train because there are fewer parameters to tune. However, this is the opposite. The frozen network takes 116 sec while the unfrozen takes 105 sec. Why would this be? Is it overhead from the Keras model?

Comment: Did you check if your model is actually not training the layers? Make sure you set "trainable = False" **before compiling**. You can do a `model.layers[i].get_weights()` before and after training to compare if the weights are actually the same.

Comment: I've noticed a huge difference in time when using keras if I keep creating new models and training over and over. In my case, I create a model, and train it with 240 seconds in each epoch. While I keep creating models with the exact same architecture and same data, but different weights, losses, etc, these models start getting slower and slower, up to more than 400 seconds per epoch. -- So, there is in fact something about keras that slows it down when you create more models. (Don't know if it's a memory thing or what...)

Comment: Ya I checked that and it is freezing it. Interesting... I am generating multiple models

Comment: This is likely related to what is actually happening in the backend, i.e. Theano/TensorFlow. From a high level perspective it is hard to say what computations are actually executed on the GPU (I assume it does not run on CPU) in what manner and this certainly needs closer inspection, if you want to debug the issue in detail.